# Qt C++11 string lists intersection via substring comparation

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt, c++11, std

I have some problem with string lists comparations. I need to reach good performance so I searched several ways for that, and now I try to use std::set_intersection to reach that.

Major problem is I need to compare these ones via substrings, for example I have this lists:

## 1

```
111111
111222
222333
333444
```

## 2

```
444111
555222
666333
777444
555111
222111
111555
```

Let's guess I used filter, which will make substr from first 3 digits from these strings (just for example, I just already done this function). And in result I need to get that intersection:

```
111111
111222
111555
222111
222333
```

Now my code looks like:

```
QSharedPointer<QStringList> Intersection_Op::compute(QSharedPointer<QStringList> leftList,
                                                     QSharedPointer<QStringList> rightList,
                                                     QPair<int, int> filters)
{
    if (!leftList or !rightList)
        return QSharedPointer<QStringList>( nullptr );
    
    std::sort( leftList->begin(), leftList->end() );
    std::sort( rightList->begin(), rightList->end() );

    // std::string getCheckBody( const QString* str, QPair<int, int> filters )
    
    auto leftStdList = new std::list<QString>( leftList );
    auto rightStdList = new std::list<QString>( rightList );
    auto result = QSharedPointer<QStringList>( new QStringList() );

    std::set_intersection(leftStdList->begin(), leftStdList->end(),
                          rightStdList->begin(), rightStdList->end(), std::back_inserter( *result ),
                              [=] (const QString& one, const QString& two) -> bool {
         auto o = getCheckBody( one, filters );
         auto t = getCheckBody( two, filters );

         // got this condition from another thread here
         return  ( o.size() == t.size() )
                 ? (o < t)
                 : ( o.size() < t.size() );
    });

    delete leftStdList;
    delete rightStdList;
    
    return result;
}
```

And now I get this result:

```
111111
222333
```

Firstly, ignoring other values with same data in first list, secondly, ignoring second list. Second one can be solved by duplicate this function with switching lists. But how can I include all values, which I need in one list (at least)?

I never used before comparation functions in algorithms, and specially for string comparing, I suspect that I used wrong conditions for that. And maybe I use wrong method (std::set_intersection)?

About data sizes, it is ~100k string lists usually, so I'm really searching how to optimize this task.

Can you help me find the solution, please? And can anyone give some advices for this task?

Thanks

Comment: Your code is not a MVE so there is no way of really knowing if the main issue  is in the code your provided. But if it is about how much memory you need to run your algorithm, then you've got to worry about the memory leak that we can only assume there is: why on earth are you using new without delete ?? Why are you using new at all ???

Comment: Sorry, didn't think need to add that in this post, but if context is important, I added full test method code.

And yes, I know that I use and std and qt stuff here, just I testing algorithm now, and edit previous version which used Qt stuff.

Comment: No need of all those pointers, `std::list<QString> leftStdList(leftList);` would be fine.

Comment: @Jarod42 no need for `leftStdList` at all

Comment: It seems that `std::set_intersection` only catch unique intersections. Even if it shouldn't.

Comment: @Fareanor It follows the mathematical definition of (multi)set intersection

Comment: @Caleth Oh right, I missed what you quoted in your answer in the documentation (and I did not refresh the question before commenting :p).

Comment: @jarod42 I set pointers, because potentially this code have to compute thousands and thousands lines of text so I can't use that in stack.

Comment: From what you say, usage of your pointers is not required: `std::list<QString>` (or even `std::vector<QString>`) is fine, just pass them by reference instead of by copy. (`QStringList Intersection_Op::compute(const QStringList& leftList,
                                                     const QStringList& rightList,
                                                     QPair<int, int> filters)`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::set_intersection` is the wrong method for this.

> If some element is found `m` times in `[first1, last1)` and `n` times in `[first2, last2)`, the first `std::min(m, n)` elements will be copied from the first range to the destination range.

You have "111..." twice in one and once in the other, and "222..." once in each.

You need something like

```
template<class InputIt1, class InputIt2,
         class OutputIt, class Compare>
OutputIt my_intersection(InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1,
                         InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2,
                         OutputIt d_first, Compare comp)
{
    while (first1 != last1 && first2 != last2) {
        auto range1 = std::equal_range(first1, last1, *first2, comp);
        auto range2 = std::equal_range(first2, last2, *first1, comp);

        d_first = std::copy(range1.first, range1.second, d_first);
        d_first = std::copy(range2.first, range2.second, d_first);

        first1 = range1.second;
        first2 = range2.second;
    }
    return d_first;
}
```

Note that you need to sort the inputs by your comparison function. Your code is ill-formed if `<` gives a different order to your lambda, e.g. if you want to compare by suffix not prefix.

Comment: Thanks a lot man for navigation and this example : ) , finally I reworked this variant a bit, also I needed to sort lists before like u said. But in some cases your variant can lost data, because just can jump through in one of lists. ( first1 / first 2 = range1 / range2.second ).

P.S: How can I add code to this comment? I'm just newbie here xD.

Comment: @std-glimmer That's how we advance the loop. The end iterator is always one past the elements we are interested in. You can use ` for code in comments